# Android visual editor doesn't allow editing

Tags: android, eclipse

Properties in the Outline-view are mostly in seemingly disabled state, while using Android visual editor. Only those properties, which already had some content when opening a layout-file are available for editing. Others might pop up some window when clicked, but even after selecting something nothing gets changed.

There doesn't seem to be anything meaningful to update via Android SDK Manager or among the Eclipse-plugins. I'm using Eclipse 3.7. What's wrong with the editor?

[Android Visual editor properties http://hoito.org/kuvat/toisaanne/eclipse-androidvisualeditor-properties.png](http://hoito.org/kuvat/toisaanne/eclipse-androidvisualeditor-properties.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the property line has gray background (what you describe as "disabled"), it means that property has the "default" value set. In that case, no attribute entry is set in the xml.

If you select multiple elements, properties are shown **gray** if *none* of the elements has that property set, **white and empty** if the property is set by *some but not all* elements, and **white with text** when *all* selected elements have the same value. Note that multi-selection only works properly when you use the "sort alphabetically" button.

At times, the property editor can be a bit unwilling, but if you double click an entry shown in the popup, or press enter when selecting a proposed value, the property should be set.

Comment: Actually I could click those entries in a popup like tens of times and nothing would get set. Pop up just appears again. If I try to double click properties like Max Lines, Lines or Max Ems, I'm not granted a possibility to write a value myself (no popup, no editable field).

That is what I call "seeming disabled"; there is partial respond to my tries to edit the properties, which weren't initially set to have a value.

Comment: Although ADT states it supports Eclipse 3.6.2+, you might want to try running ADT on the latest eclipse version. Maybe that solves the problem for you?

Comment: I downgraded the ADT Plugin to (randomly selected) version 22.0.5. Now I have no problems editing the properties. However that version doesn't support the latest rendering libraries (API 19, for example).

Comment: Let me correct myself.. there isn't need for downgrading the ADT Plugin. To fix the issue, I had to use some other rendering target than Android 4.4 (API 19). If I select Android 4.3 (API 18) or lower version, I have no problems editing properties. I guess I can live with that for now.