# How to select an older API version in Android graphical editor?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

[I'm asking this here (again) as I cannot yet comment on answers in the question I have linked to]

I am having the exact same problem described here

[Android eclipse editor: Unable to edit properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579594/android-eclipse-editor-unable-to-edit-properties?answertab=active#tab-top)

and here

[Android visual editor doesn't allow editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051532/android-visual-editor-doesnt-allow-editing)

I will ad that I can edit these properties if I leave the graphical layout and go into the xml file and add for example

android:textColor="xxxxxx"

This then allows me to edit that property from the editor but this is quite tedious as I  have to do this for each property I wish to edit.

I am using ADT Build: v22.3.0-887826 which I downloaded today (21.11.2013).

I want to try the solution suggested in the avbove links i.e lower the API version. However, I cannot select an older version here. The only option available when I click on the robot icon is API19:Android4.4.

Does anyone know how I can select an older API and see if this solution works for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Android SDK Manager

[image]

and download SDK Platform for older APIs.

[image]